# What is default color for text in textview?

Tags: android, colors, textview, default, android-gui

I set the color to red , and after that I want to set the color again back to default, but I do not know what is default color, does anyone knows ?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You can save old color and then use it to restore the original value. Here is an example:

```
ColorStateList oldColors =  textView.getTextColors(); //save original colors
textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
....
textView.setTextColor(oldColors);//restore original colors
```

---

But in general default `TextView` text color is determined from current Theme applied to your `Activity`.

Comment: Most correct solution. Preserve text color states (disabled, etc)

Comment: From my observation, text color defined by theme is not inherited by TextView added dynamically from code. It always appears in white regardless of dark/light theme.

Comment: @shiouming Depends of the Context used. Every Constructor uses a Context, and in that Context, a Theme is set (usually default). If needed, use the [TextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#TextView(android.content.Context,%20android.util.AttributeSet,%20int,%20int))

Comment: But! After for example theme changing oldColors was color for old theme - so it's not completely working solution. As alternative: You can add to the layout invisible TextView - and get default text color from it.

Answer (score 139):

Actually the color TextView is:

```
android:textColor="@android:color/tab_indicator_text"
```

or

```
#808080
```

Comment: That is the default tab indicator text color.  In many cases it may be the same as the default text color, but I wouldn't rely on it.

Comment: Very close, but this colour is not the same.

Comment: @LukTar is right, I used photoshop and checked the color...  #737373 is the textview text color from a point pixel sample (sample area size of one pixel) on a view zoomed to 1000% in android studio...  i think you need to look at the app's default style to get the actual value for any particualr app though...

Comment: Also, it does not exists in `marshmallow`

Answer (score 41):

There are some default colors defined in `android.R.color`

```
int c = getResources().getColor(android.R.color.primary_text_dark);
```

Comment: It should be `int c = ...` instead of `Color c = ...`

Comment: As of API level23, `getResources().getColor(int id)` is now deprecated (see [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColor%28int%29)). You can either use  `getResources().getColor (int id, Resources.Theme theme)` or `ContextCompat.getColor(contex, android.R.color.primary_text_dark)`

Comment: primary_text_dark is now deprecated but no idea why :(

Answer (score 18):

Get these values from attributes:

```
int[] attrs = new int[] { android.R.attr.textColorSecondary };
TypedArray a = getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(R.style.AppTheme, attrs);
DEFAULT_TEXT_COLOR = a.getColor(0, Color.RED);
a.recycle();
```

Comment: This looks like it will properly select the colour based on theme, and will update for instance, if the app is in night mode.

Comment: To get the TypedArray for the current Theme call it without the Theme arg: TypedArray a = getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs);

Comment: This will only get an appropriate color if the theme is actually using textColorSecondary. Since it is possible to override this in a theme or style, this is not a very accurate way of determining what the default text color for a particular view will actually be.

Note also that individual views can now be themed, so the theme associated with the view's context should be used instead of assuming the activity's theme is in effect for all of its views.

Answer (score 12):

There are defaults in the theme that Android uses if you don't specifiy a text color. It may be different colors in various Android UIs (e.g. HTC Sense, Samsung TouchWiz, etc). Android has a `_dark` and `_light` theme, so the defaults are different for these (but nearly black in both of them in vanilla android). It is however good practice to define your primary text color yourself for to provide a consistent style throughout the devices.

In code:

```
getResources().getColor(android.R.color.primary_text_dark);
getResources().getColor(android.R.color.primary_text_light);
```

In xml:

```
android:color="@android:color/primary_text_dark"
android:color="@android:color/primary_text_light"
```

As reference in vanilla Android the dark theme text color is [`#060001`](http://www.color-hex.com/color/060001) and the in the light theme it's [`#060003`](http://www.color-hex.com/color/060003) since API v1. [See the android style class here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color.html)

Comment: The colors referenced in your last link are actually not colors at all, they are just android.R values that are used to look up the color. You can look up the default colors by finding the color in [this directory](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/color/) and looking up the base color reference in [this .xml file](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/values/colors.xml).

Answer (score 9):

I know it is old but according to my own theme editor with default light theme, default

`textPrimaryColor = #000000`

and

```
textColorPrimaryDark = #757575
```

Answer (score 5):

It may not be possible in all situations, but why not simply use the value of a different random TextView that exists in the same Activity and that carries the colour you are looking for?

```
txtOk.setTextColor(txtSomeOtherText.getCurrentTextColor());
```

Comment: this is the safest way

Answer (score 4):

I used a color picker on the textview and got this #757575

Answer (score 2):

The color of text inside a `TextView` is totally dependent on your theme.
The easiest way to know it:

1. Add a `TextView` to any xml file
2. Select the `TextView`
3. Click on `Split` view
4. Open the `Attributes` tab and scroll to the color section.

[image]

As you can see, according to my theme it is: `@android:color/secondary_text_material_light`

Comment: Do you know how to change it to primary_text?

Comment: @user2872856 you can do so by changing it in the theme

Answer (score 1):

There are some default colours which get defined in the Themes of app. Below is the code snippet which you can use to get the current default color programmatically.

```
protected int getDefaultTextColor(){
        TextView textView = new TextView(getContext());
        return textView.getCurrentTextColor();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the default color integer value is 16711935 (0x00FF00FF).

Comment: wow hardcoded stuff, you know. Was this the value for all Android versions on all devices and with all selectable themes?! Joking, You know... :)

Comment: So the default text color in android is pink? I think it is more inline with #060001 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color.html#primary_text_dark

Comment: But I believe that default text color is green

Answer (score 0):

> hey you can try this

```
ColorStateList colorStateList = textView.getTextColors();
String hexColor = String.format("#%06X", (0xFFFFFF & colorStateList.getDefaultColor()));
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that `android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_dark"` provides a closer result to the default TextView color than `android:textColor="@android:color/tab_indicator_text"`.
I suppose you have to switch between secondary_text_dark/light depending on the Theme you are using

Answer (score 0):

You could use TextView.setTag/getTag to store original color before making changes. I would suggest to create an unique id resource in ids.xml to differentiate other tags if you have.

before setting to other colors:

```
if (textView.getTag(R.id.txt_default_color) == null) {
    textView.setTag(R.id.txt_default_color, textView.currentTextColor)
}
```

Changing back:

```
textView.getTag(R.id.txt_default_color) as? Int then {
    textView.setTextColor(this)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no default color. It means that every device can have own.

Comment: No there are default colors, just that every android distribution can overwrite them

Comment: @for3st Do you know of cases that they do change it?