# How to get the default text color for android TextView?

Tags: android, view, colors, textview, themes

I cannot get the default gray text color for TextView (and maybe other views) in Android 23.

I tried to get it with this code :

```
TextView textview= (TextView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.my_textview);

int colorFirstTry = title.getCurrentTextColor(); // black
int colorSecondTry = title.getTextColors().getDefaultColor(); // black
int colorthirdTry = ContextCompat.getColor(mActivity, android.R.color.primary_text_light); // black
```

My theme is the default theme used in an blank activity project (AppTheme from Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar parent). Colors are blue, darker blue and purple for respectively colorPrimary, colorPrimaryDark and colorAccent.

When i navigate through all Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar parents, i find a similar gray value :

```
<style name="Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Platform.AppCompat.Light">   
    ...
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark_material_light</item>
```

But this value shoud be overrided by my app theme value.

Answer (score 30):

As said by Alex [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33176972/906630), you can get it by:

```
android:textColor="@android:color/tab_indicator_text"
```

or

```
#808080
```

It worked great for me!

Comment: Worked great!
I used it programmatically in this way:
`textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.tab_indicator_text));`

Answer (score 3):

please check this answer:

> You can save old color and then use it to restore the original value.
> Here is an example:
>
> ```
> ColorStateList oldColors =    textView.getTextColors(); //save original colors
> textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
> ....
> textView.setTextColor(oldColors);//restore original colors
> ```
>
> ---
>
> But in general default `TextView` text color is determined from current Theme applied to your `Activity`.

From: [What is default color for text in textview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468602/what-is-default-color-for-text-in-textview)

Hope it help

Comment: Same problem, the color is black in debug (#000000) but gray on my device and inside the design window.

Comment: maybe it's depend on style used by phone. Let me guess are you using Samsung? :-)

Comment: It's an Honor phone !

Comment: best solution so far

Answer (score 1):

Best way according to google is

```
title.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
title.setAlpha(0.54f);
```

when you want set other color reset the alpha to 1.0f

source: [Google Material Design](https://material.google.com/style/color.html#color-text-background-colors)