# What is the default text color on Android and iOS?

Tags: react-native

I was trying to figure out the default text color on Android and iOS in react-native.

Is the default color of  the default of Android? I found - https://stackoverflow.com/a/33176972/1828637

Is it really `#808080`? Anyway to programtically get this?

Comment: Check this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468602/what-is-default-color-for-text-in-textview/33176972#comment45329621_6468781).

Comment: The accepted answer to the post you linked says that for Android, it's based on the current theme. There are other answers that reference where and , how those theme colors are defined, and how to get them programatically. Only one of the answers in that linked post say anything about #808080 AFAICT.

Comment: @KenWhite but im not sure if React Native takes the Android default, or has a default of its own. I couldn't find a default in react-native code base so was thinking it was Android default.

Comment: Why would  React not use the default theme colors selected by the user?