# How to get TextView default color

Tags: android, textview, android-theme

I have a TextView defined in xml. The `textColor` attribute fieild in the Android Studio properties pannel shows `[default] "@android:color/secondary_text_material_light"`.

How to get this default color programmically to reset a TextView color when needed?

PS: I've read through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468602/what-is-default-color-for-text-in-textview) but it does not seem to answer my question.

Comment: Why doesn't the linked post answer your question?

Comment: is the problem getting the color from resources or setting the text color programmatically?

Comment: @PrateekKumar the accepted answer in that post suggests saving the default color before changing it which I consider a workarround rather than a solution. Alternative anwers there suggest using `getColor` functions with a resource id, but `android.R.color.secondary_text_material_light` throughs unresolved reference for me to some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with the following workaround solution.

```
textView.setTextColor(TextView(context).textColors)
```

Comment: This put me on the right lines to figuring out what seems to be a working solution. In Java it's `myTextView.setTextColor(myTextView.getTextColors())`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a color defined as a color resource programmatically with this line of code.

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.secondary_text_material_light);
```

I haven´t tested, but i think it should work.
I hope i could help.

**EDIT 1:**
If the problem is to set the text color...

You can change it via the `textView.setTextColor()` method.
The full code could look like this:

```
your_text_view.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.secondary_text_material_light));
```

Comment: `android.R.color.secondary_text_material_light` throughs unresolved reference to me to some reason

Comment: Ok instead of `android.R.color.secondary_text_material_light` you could use the private value `R.color.secondary_text_default_material_light` which is the direct hex color from `android.R.color.secondary_text_material_light`, but this is a workaround too. Maybe a better than save the color value before changing as in the other SO post. I dont know... But do you get an unsolved reference error with this resource value too?

Comment: The second resource does work but as you have noted yourself, it throughs the private resource warning.

Comment: Ok, last approach, i found recently... You can use `android.R.color.tab_indicator_text` as the color is the same. This method gives you no warnings, but is still a workaround. But maybe a better one. I dont know any other "solutions" as `android.R.color.secondary_text_material_light` doesnt work.